# No route matches [GET] "/" (ActionController::RoutingError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have an application running on this url correctly

```
http://workspace-username.c9users.io/?#/bookings
```

and i have my server running on port 8081.

When i run my `cucumber` in line

```
visit  http://workspace-username.c9users.io/?#/bookings
```

it gives me the erorr:

```
   No route matches [GET] "/" (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

I just got suprised because, the application is running as well, but `capybara` can not get it.
 I have also tried

```
visit  http://workspace-username.c9users.io:8081/?#/bookings
```

but still got the same erorr

Comment: What driver are you using? The default racktest driver can't connect to non-local urls so it ignores host names

Comment: what do  you mean driver?

Comment: Capybara supports multiple drivers, if you want to connect to remote sites, you'll need to use one other than racktest - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers

Answer (score 1):

When accessing external pages capybara needs to use a web driver other than racktest because racktest only talks to rack applications. To test the website you will want to use another driver like selenium.

You could set the driver to selenium if you only need it for that test.

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
```

Or change the default driver when you configure rspec

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

Comment: where should i add thiss line?

Comment: The first can go in the test file itself, as you would only want it to apply to that group of tests. The second generally goes in the rails helper file inside the Rspec configure block.

Comment: Setting the `default_driver` worked for me (`current_driver` did not).